# Why should I use the "BurnRecovery" tool

Tags: backup

I just bought a new laptop and I'm quite puzzled by the restore utility. Why should I use the "BurnRecovery" tool which burns the default image on a DVD when I have the default image partition on my disk?

Comment: Better hope that partition never has a problem. Two recovery possibilities would be silly.

Comment: Why should I take up valuable trunk space with a spare tire when I have four perfectly good tires already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make the recovery disk in case the HDD that holds your recovery partition dies.

Alternatively you could use the OS's in-built backup to make an image backup (assuming it supports that option).

Comment: Thanks. Since I prefer a clean installation without the manufacturer's default software package, I guess I'll just skip this extra backup.

Comment: @Grant - the point is what if the hard drive actually dies, as in the recovery partition is no longer readable and you have to replace the drive?  If you have not burned the DVD, you're going to have to contact the OEM if you want a factory image . . .

Comment: @Grant Just make sure you have an install disk for the OS, or when that HDD dies you'll be here trying to figure out where to get one. ;)

Comment: Note that, in addition to making the backup copy, you may have to make a boot DVD.

Comment: It's lots of fun to run down the drivers when you've got a totally hosed disk and the hardware won't talk to standard OS installs (which is dirt-common on laptops.) "I'll just get them from the net" - but I have no usable network adapters without the drivers. "I'll put them on USB stick" - but it won't talk to the USB ports. Fun, fun, fuuuun....well, you'll have to learn by going there, I suppose.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I forgot to mention that I have a retail version of Windows 8 that's better than the OEM. By the way, funnily enough the HDD failed fatally just after a couple of months.